# Overcome translation Workbench drawback

Tags: apex, visualforce, customsetting, translation-workbench

I have requirement where I have Polish language to do double translation. Like say if User Language is Polish and User Profile 'A', I need to show my custom object 'X' as 'Y'. When User language is Polish and User Profile 'B' I need to show my custom object Name 'Z'. Is this achievable by some custom settings or so?

Translation workbench operates on only User language. Can I make it customized to operate on both User language and profile. Thus my custom object label will show 'Polish Object1' if User language and profile respectively is 'Polish' and 'Profile1' ; 'Polish Object 2' if User language and profile respectively is 'Polish' and 'Profile2'

Comment: Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: I thought your question was clear, but I was hesitant to answer because I don't think that there is a way to do it. As far as I know, there can only be one translation per language. When you retrieve the translation metadata, it looks like you can have a translation set up for language and region, but in my experience, only one locale will work per language. i.e. `en_US` works, but not `en_CA`. Even then though, the Polish language only has one locale, so even if object translations did work that way, you couldn't use it as a work around for that language. ​